# Stopped DefaultMessageListenerContainer after its initialization

Tags: java, spring, jms

I want the Spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer to be stopped after its initialization. Is there any way to configure this point?

I've tried to set autoStartup property to false, but it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a stupid mistake in spring context configuration.

The part of it:

```
<bean id="jmsInContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    ....
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

But this property is overridden by:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter .... container="jmsInContainer" auto-startup="true"/>
```